# HTML - Open Mobile Device Camera directly without gallary, files and other options

Tags: android, html, asp.net, ajax, camera

I am trying to open a Mobile device's camera directly thru HTML and Ajax  `AsyncFileUpload` control.

Below is the sample code:

```
<cc1:AsyncFileUpload OnClientUploadError="uploadError" Width="300px" CssClass="form-group" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" runat="server" ID="AsyncFileUpload1" UploaderStyle="Traditional" CompleteBackColor="White" ThrobberID="imgLoader" UploadingBackColor="#CCFFCC" OnClientUploadStarted="uploadStart" OnUploadedComplete="FileUploadComplete" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

When I browse the page on the Mobile device and tap the "choose file" button, these options are provided:

1. Camera
2. Camcorder
3. Voice Recorder
4. Gallery
5. Files
6. Documents
7. Other Options

Here is a sample screenshot from an Android Samsung Galaxy A7 device:

[image]

But I want to display only the Camera Option and hide the other options.